# AccessViolation debugging fun

Tags: c++, debugging, memory, pointers, access-violation

I have a block of c++ code that looks something like this psuedocode:

```
LPBYTE FindBits(const BITMAPINFOHEADER *pbi)
{
    return (LPBYTE)pbi + pbi->biSize + FindColorTableBytes(pbi);
}
```

It gets a pointer to the acctual dib (bitmap) data.

Now, I have a multithreaded c# application that is loading bitmaps from all different files (thoeoretically) never the same one at a time. It uses my C++ dll to handle reading and decoding the bitmaps from the documents.

**The problem** is that I am attempting to make this library safe on multiple threads, but I am getting an AccessViolationError at the line in the function above. While trying to debug this problem the debugger breaks when the error occurs and I look at the members of pbi. They look like so:

```
{biSize=??? biWidth=??? biHeight=??? ...}
```

**pbi is** bitmap memory that was locked using GlobalLock(handleToDib) and to even get to the above function to get the access violation GlobalLock has to return a non-null pointer.

when I look at the memory location returned by GlobalLock in the memory window it looks like so:

> ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ??

If the debugger was giving me a magic number I could understand if the memory was bad... but this is confusing to me... and apparently the debugger. Does anyone know why the debugger is displaying this?

Comment: Somewhere along the way, the pointer to the structure is changed to point to something else. Have you stepped over the code the calls `GlobalLock` to see that it returns a valid pointer?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg tryin, its hard because its such a big library and it most definately seems to be an issue with multithreading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MSVS debugger is good enough.
Use Memory window to see raw structure of objects, and Disassembly windows to precisely execute instructions.

Of course OllyDbg can be more handy for such tasks (for people who know how to use it), but it's not as easy as MSVS' debugger.

Comment: I think your right, it is good enough, but I cant explain the last part where the memory window only displays ?? ?? ?? ?? for each byte

Comment: @TomFobear, it displays "??" because pointer is invalid - it points to non-existent memory page.

Comment: It seems most definately an issue with 2 different threads calling GlobalUnlock at the same time. Though i pass two completely different pointers to it. I dont really have the proof yet but it breaks in one of two locations, both after a GlobalLock.